# Liferay new portlet vs plugin project difference

Tags: java, liferay, portal, liferay-ide

I'm using Eclipse and have the Liferay plugin installed and trying to create a new portlet. I want the Liferay IDE to pre-generate as much code as possible

Does anyone know what the main differences are between creating a new Liferay Portlet and a Liferay Plugin Project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Liferay Plugin Project allows you to create a project (of type portlet, theme, hook etc..), with all dependencies and settings that you need to start coding (or almost).

Liferay portlet adds to one of your plugin projects **of type portlet** a class (the **portlet class**) and optionally a JSP. But you have to tell the portlet how use this class and jsp, and probably many other missing settings.

I suggest you always use the Liferay Plugin Project, its simpler and fast.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use a different explanation than Marco:

A plugin project is what you add to the IDE - This is where your actual plugins live. Eclipse organizes around projects, and the projects are what makes up a plugin for Liferay. As the IDE interprets different kinds of projects in a different way (e.g. standalone Java Applications vs. "Dynamic Web projects" etc), a "Portlet Project" or "Theme Project" just adds to this list.

Once you have a plugin project (of type "Portlet") you can add as many portlets to it as you like. Thus, if you're developing portlets, you'll always have a minimum of one portlet plugin. This portlet plugin can hold any number of portlets.

You'll always deploy the whole plugin to Liferay - this fact might influence which portlets you want to group into a single plugin.